# Скажите пожалуйста ошибку в коде

Tags: c, массивы, структуры

Скажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка. Почему не выводит на экран имена с фамилиями при совпадении? (Без использовании библиотеки string.h)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){ 
    char str;
    int i, found=1;
    struct people
    {
        char name[20], surname[20];
    }   people[]=
                {
                    {"Aleksandr","Pushkin"},
                    {"Mihail","Lermantov"},
                    {"Nikolai","Gogol"},
                    {"Jack","London"},
                    {"Sharlotta","Brontte"},
                    {"Ernest","Himunguey"},
                    {"Aleksandr","Block"},
                    {"Anna","Ahmatova"},
                    {"Ura","Antonov"},
                    {"Franc","Kafka"}
                };
    printf ("Введите имя: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {   
        if (str==people[i].name[0])
        {
            found=0;
            printf ("Найдено: %s %s\n",people[i].name,people[i].surname);
        }
        
    }
        if (found)
            printf ("Совпадений не найдено.");
}
```

Comment: Оно у вас не то что работать — компилироваться не должно... `scanf("%s", str);` — вы пытаетесь считать слово *куда*?...

Comment: Точно, спасибо, забыл поставить амперсанд, не заметил

Comment: Ответ неверный :) Читать слово в `char` не получится, нужен массив...